# Wordpress URL Rewriting Ignores Existing Files

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have wordpress installed at the web root directory of a server. I also have a file called test.php in the same directory that is not at all related or connected to wordpress (atleast not by any code within the test.php file). if i go to http://myurl.com/test.php i get my theme's styling and the wordpress error message for when it can't find a post at that particular url.

Is there a UI element in the Admin dashboard that allows you to change this behavior (I can't find one, but I wouldn't be surprised if I've overlooked it) or do I have to edit the modrewrite rules myself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the .htaccess `RewriteRule` generated by a WordPress install I have. Note the `RewriteCond`s:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`!-f` means if a file at that path does not exist. `!-d` means if a directory at that path does not exist.

Comment: yeah, the .htaccess in the webroot also has the `!-f` and `!-d` flags on the rewrite conditions... I know how modrewrite works, it just doesn't appear to be running as expected right now... I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you say your `.htaccess` has the correct `RewriteCond`, it is most likely misconfigured, or perhaps there are conflicting statements?

Can you post the entire contents of your `.htaccess`?